# to make the button clicked when enter pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
<select name="category" id="category">
             <option value="select" selected="selected" style="display:none;">--Select Search Category--</option>
      <option value="Title">Book Title</option>
      <option value="Subtitle">Book Subtitle</option>
      <option value="BookAccessNumber">Book Access Number</option>
      <option value="Author">Author</option>
      <option value="Publisher">Publisher</option>

    </select> 
            <input type="text" name="keyword" value="" id="keyword" />
             <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="display(category.value,keyword.value)">
              <br/><br/>
              <div id="show_result">
              </div>
```

In my code I get some input values , one from combo box and other from textbox and I'm having a button called search. What I done is if I click the button it will call a java script function called `display()`, which is used to display the results of search.

But I give the event as onClick, so it works only when I click the button. It doesn't work when I press enter.
What I need to do is, to make the function `display(`) called even I hit "enter" too.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the display method check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/6qj45s9j/):

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("call display method");
        display();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/cy84t4pz/1/

Use jquery trigger

```
function display(){
alert('hellow btn clicked');
}

$('.addButton').on('click', display);

$('body').on('keypress','input', function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $('.addButton').trigger("click")
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your input elements in a `form` and move the `onclick` handler to the `onsubmit` handler of the form.

```
<form onsubmit="alert('foo'); return false;">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: this is not working both in button click and enter press. Any other answer please

Comment: But i need to call a function in `onsubmit` it not working, if i do so

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="display(category.value,keyword.value)" onKeyDown="if(arguments[0].KeyCode==13){display(category.value,keyword.value)}">
```

Comment: is event parameter accessible within onKeyDown ?

Comment: this is not working.. its working only on button click, not on enter press

Answer (score 0):

Move your input elements to a `<form>` and change your `<input type="button">` to `<input type="submit">`. A form will treat the pressing of `Enter` key as clicking on the `Submit` button. So, the form will be processed.

Try this:

```
<form onsubmit="display(category.value,keyword.value)">
    <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="select" selected="selected" style="display:none;">--Select Search Category--</option>
        <option value="Title">Book Title</option>
        <option value="Subtitle">Book Subtitle</option>
        <option value="BookAccessNumber">Book Access Number</option>
        <option value="Author">Author</option>
        <option value="Publisher">Publisher</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="text" name="keyword" value="" id="keyword" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<br/><br/>
<div id="show_result">
</div>
```

Please note that `display(category.value,keyword.value)` is moved to the `onsubmit` attribute of the `form`.